# Longest forced win after 3 moves

Tags: problems, checkmate, puzzles, records

It is possible to reach (exactly) #8 after just 3 moves:

```
[Title "#8 after 3 moves"]
[FEN ""]

1. e3 f6 2. Qf3 Kf7 3. Nh3 Qe8! 4. Ng5+ Kg6 5. Bd3+ Kxg5 6. Qf4+ Kh5 7. g4+ Kh4 8. Qg3+ Kg5 9. f4+ Kh6 10. g5+ fxg5 11. Qxg5#
```

Is there any longer forced win than #8 that can be reached (and proven) after just 3 moves?

This question is a *variant* of, and therefore not a duplicate, ["The quickest mate in n."](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34876/the-quickest-mate-in-n)

Comment: Just two minor comments: For a brute force attack, you have to check about 100 million positions (quickly googled that; with some intelligent guessing you surely can bring that down - 1.e~ is probably forced, and likewise 1...d/e/f~). Second, it would also be remarkable if the resulting position would be correct as a chess problem (e.g. here h4+ works as well as f4+).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After playing around in [Lichess's analysis page,](https://lichess.org/analysis#0) I found a **mate in 10.** Throwing the moves into [chess.com's analysis page](https://www.chess.com/analysis) provides further confirmation. It has a few wholly unique lines, and some dualed ones, making it reminiscent of a chess problem per @Hauke Reddmann's above comment.

```
[FEN ""]
[Title "#10 After 3 Moves"]

1. e4 d5 2. h3 Kd7 3. Bb5+ Ke6 4. Qg4+ Kd6 5. e5+ Kc5 6. b4+ Kxb5 7. a4+ Kb6 8. a5+ Kc6 9. b5+ Kc5 10. Ba3+ Kxb5 11. Nc3+ Kc6 12. Qa4+ b5 13. Qxb5#
```

It can be done the other way around as well.

```
[Title "#10 After 2.5 Moves"]
[FEN ""]

1. d4 e5 2. Kd2 Bb4+ 3. Ke3 Qg5+ 4. Kd3 e4+ 5. Kc4 b5+ 6. Kxb4 a5+ 7. Kc3 b4+ 8. Kb3 a4+ 9. Kc4 Ba6+ 10. Kxb4 Nc6+ 11. Kc3 Qa5+ 12. b4 Qxb4#
```

Comment: Well, in terms of finding "what is the theoretical perfect line of play for Black after `1. e4` we can strike `2...Kd7 3...Ke6` off that list.

Comment: Impressive. (I tried out a few other setups on the queenside, but no luck.)