# The quickest selfmate in 2

Tags: problems, records, selfmate

[Duh.](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33168/the-quickest-selfmate-in-1)

Clearly, the one shown there with Qxh5+ Rxh5# can be easily turned into a s#2, by e.g. B-e2-f3, Qe2 from White and c6, Q-a5xd2-d1 from Black. 9.0 moves if I added correctly. Someone care to beat this, or even construct a helpgame-s#3? (This might be *far* trickier than a [#n](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36788/the-fastest-dualed-mates-in-n) counterpart!)

Addendum: This example doesn't work as the Black queen vacates d8 for the Black king.

Answer (score 1):

I care to do it in 7.0 moves.

```
[FEN ""]

1. f4 e5 2. Kf2 Ke7 3. Kg3 Kf6 4. Kh4 Kf5+ 5. Kh5 e4 6. e3 d5 7. h4 Qe7 8. Qg4+ Kf6 9. Qg6+ fxg6#
```

Comment: With a careful move order you can save a whole move pair, also, that one can be turned into a s#3 with a move added again (and s#4 is also easy). I leave you pondering ;-)